# Disable Ctrl + V in Microsoft Excel (allow paste with right-click)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel spreadsheet used by me and my team. This spreadsheet uses conditional formatting, so I'd like my team to NOT use Ctrl + V and instead right-click and use 'paste as values'. When they use Ctrl + V, it causes the conditional formatting to fragment over time. I've told them about this, and I've added a popup message reminder using Data Validation, but they still use Ctrl + V!

I want to disable pasting with Ctrl + V, and add a msgbox to Ctrl + V.

Here's my VBA (I bound pasteWarn() to Ctrl + V). It doesn't seem to have any effect at all - the msgbox doesn't appear, and ctrl + V works as normal.

```
Sub pasteGone()
'Disable CTRL + V.
Application.OnKey "^{v}", "" 'Paste
End Sub

Sub pasteWarn()
' Bind this to Ctrl + V
MsgBox "Ctrl + V has been disabled. Please right-click and use 'Paste as Values'."
End Sub
```

Possible complication: my team and I use a mix of Office 2016, 2013 and 2010. (I'm on 2016; they're all either on 2010 and 2013.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question as it is, but perhaps a way to solve the problem anyways.

Instead of forcing the users to adapt to the workbook, make the workbook adapt the input to suit the workbook.
Meaning, when the user pastes something, undo what they did and paste it as values instead.
That way they can do paste with CTRL+V and it will still be correct.
You have to set a break point in the code on the lastAction line and see what "Paste" is in your language then use that in the If.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1)

  If lastAction = "Paste" Then ' change to your language
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Undo
        End With
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Add the above code to the sheet(s) you want this on. You can also use the Target if you wish to limit the PasteValues to only a part of the sheet.

Comment: Thank you! That works a treat!

Comment: @InskoraBournvadus No problem! Thank you for an interesting question to solve

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue previously, the only work around I could find was to stop the user being able to copy. ( i know this may not be exactly what you are after, as they may still need to use copy )

I used the below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.OnKey "^c", ""
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
    Application.OnKey "^c"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
 Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.OnKey "^c", ""
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
    Application.OnKey "^c"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.OnKey "^c", ""
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Copying and Pasting into the skills matrix has been disabled to prevent changes in the workbook functionality."
End Sub
```